# How to get history of previous three clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

```js
var myFunction = function() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var e = this.value;
    var current_value = localStorage.getItem("check");
    if (current_value == "null") {
      current_value = e;
    } else {
      current_value = current_value + "\n" + e;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("check", current_value);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("check"));
  } else {
    console.log('Cannot access local storage.');
  }
};
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("click_button")
for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function clickCount() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    alert(localStorage.getItem("check"));
  } else {
    alert("Cannot access local Storage");
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="first_button" class="click_button">first_button</button>
<button type="button" id="second_button" class="click_button">second_button</button>
<button type="button" id="third_button" class="click_button">third_button</button>

<button onclick="clickCount()" type="button" id="history_button">History_button</button>
```

When i click the history_button button, I have to alert the latest THREE buttons that were clicked(among first_button, second_button and third_button). This has to be done using HTML5 localStorage API.  In my solution which I did anyway(Iam not a very good coder so my who code maybe wrong), alert shows all the previous clicks instead of only last three clicks. i.Please Help.

Comment: I saw same question yesterday as well, which is already deleted. It became very popular question. it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this over your local system might help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('clickItem') === null){
      localStorage.setItem('clickItem', $(this).attr('id'));
   }
    else{
      var existing_val = localStorage.getItem('clickItem');
      localStorage.setItem('clickItem', existing_val+','+$(this).attr('id'));
  }
 });
});
 function clickCount(){
  $('#history').html('');
  var history = localStorage.getItem('clickItem');
  history = history.split(',');
  console.log(history.length-3);
  $(history).each(function(index){
   if(index > history.length -4) 
   $('#history').append(this+'<br>');
  });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="first_button" class="click_button">first_button</button>
  <button type="button" id="second_button" class="click_button">second_button</button>
  <button type="button" id="third_button" class="click_button">third_button</button>
  <button onclick="clickCount()" type="button" id="history_button">History_button</button>
  <div id="history"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should create an array of click events and maintain the same througout as a stack.

You can keep on doing the push whenever there is a click. And when you tap on history button just take the last 3 indexes from the array.

Try the below

```js
//change myFunction to this -

var myFunction = function() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var e = this.value;
    var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("check"));


    if(arr instanceof Array){
      arr.push(e);
      localStorage.setItem("check", JSON.stringify(arr));
    }    
}


//in your click count method 
function clickCount() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var items = localStorage.getItem("check");
    if( items.length > 3){
       items = items.splice(items.length - 4, 3);
    }
    alert(items);
  } else {
    alert("Cannot access local Storage");
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show some code hint..like the array creation part or the push part, as therez a bit of complexity in storing array to local storage